# Windows XP, Can run .jar from cmd prompt, but batch file errors on "Cannot access jar file"

Tags: windows-xp, batch

I am trying to create a simple batch file to start my java application from. It seems that it will not let me access the .jar file from a batch file.

Is there a special syntax for file permissions I might need to add?

File

```
cd My Documents
start javaw -jar myApp.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Java but I'm familiar with batch so:

```
pushd "C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\My Documents\"
start javaw -jar myApp.jar
```

This will work if the command `start javaw -jar myApp.jar` is a valid command

You can also user this:

```
pushd "C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\My Documents\"
start javaw -jar myApp.jar
pause
```

This way it will stop for user input prior to closing the batch so you can see what the batch file do

Once you have got it running just add `@echo off` as line 1 and remove `pause` this will just make it look a tiny bit nicer (Clean scripting)